# Nuxt Project 404 Page on Refresh of webpage

Tags: nuxt.js

I am new to nuxt. I am working on a shopping cart website. I use cookie to store a token. Header authorization will be added to token. Then send to the API to get information.
I test fine when working on local. Then I run the command “npm run generate” and upload the files to server. I find error when testing on server.
It is checked that I use nuxt-link to perform nuxt router redirect can get the information from server (in the process of select items of shopping cart). However, when I refresh the webpage (press F5), there is Internal Server Error. Would everyone advise help to solve this? Thanks!

Below is my code:
**store/index.js (I am not sure if this.$cookiz.get("usertoken") cause the problem)**

```
export const state = () => ({
    cart: {},
  });
  export const mutations = {
    SET_CART_DATA(state, value) {
      state.cart = value;
    },
  };
  export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit({ commit, dispatch }, { req }) {
      await dispatch("CartData");
    },
    async CartData({ commit }, value) {
        const config = {
          headers: { Authorization: this.$cookiz.get("usertoken") },
        };
        const { data } = await this.$axios.get(
          process.env.baseUrl + `/shopcar`,
          config
        );
        commit("SET_CART_DATA", data);
    },
  };
```

**cart.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{cart}}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
        cart: this.$store.state.cart
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Error Message:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V7zbuM-RprV0DGH-AO0SwJIY6dbrjbAm/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you share the network tab information in the developer tools its can help more

But I think after reloading the page, store become empty so there is no data to show and cause the problems, so you can use localstarage or sessionstorage to save data in your browser

I think this link can help you:

https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-permanently-save-data-with-vuex-localstorage-in-your-vue-app-f1d5c140db69